# Procurar Strings em Arquivos Texto no PHP

Tags: php, string, txt, php-7

Tenho um arquivo chamado "teste.txt" dentro dele tem várias palavras, tenho um input onde pego a palavra inserida e gostaria de verificar se essa palavra está contida dentro deste "arquivo.txt".

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP**

```
if( strpos(file_get_contents("texto.txt"),$_POST['palavra']) !== false) {
    echo "tem";
}else{
    echo "não tem";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="palavra"> 
<input type="submit" name="botao" value="Verificar"> 
</form>
```

> [**strpos**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) — Encontra a posição da primeira ocorrência de uma string
>
> [**file_get_contents**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) é o método preferível para ler o conteúdo de um arquivo em uma string.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$linhas= file("C:\\Documents and Settings\\myfile.txt");

foreach($linhas as $linha)
{
    echo($linha);
    /* Aqui compara a string */
}

?>
```

Ou se você conhece a linha em que está a palavra

```
$arq  = fopen($arquivo, 'r');
    while (!feof($arq)) {
      $linha = fgets($arq); // cria um array com o conteudo da linha atual do arquivo 
      if ((substr($linha, 23, 1) == 'palavra') ) {
          /* 23 - onde começa a palavra */
          /* 1 - número de letras */
          /* faz o que precisa */
      }  
   }
```

Dessa forma, o PHP passa linha a linha, assim, basta você comparar com um regex ou string se a palavra é igual.

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php

Answer (score 0):

Olá você pode fazer o uso do [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) em conjunto com o [strpos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) e o [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtolower.php) do PHP.

Segue um exemplo de como pode ser feito:

```
<?php
   $arquivo = strtolower(file_get_contents('teste.txt'));
   $textoBuscar = strtolower($_POST['nome_do_input']);
   if(isset($_POST)) {
     if(strpos($arquivo, $textoBuscar) !== FALSE) {
       echo '<h1>Existe a palavra ' . $_POST['nome_do_input'] . ' no teste.txt</h1>';
     } else {
       echo '<h1>Não Existe a palavra ' . $_POST['nome_do_input'] . ' no teste.txt</h1>';
     }
   }
?>

<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o que deseja consultar" />
  <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
</form>
```